# How to organize the code with actor pattern

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm converting a java application to Akka in order to learn about actor pattern.

Let's say that I have the three usual layers (application, domain, infrastructure). My domain layer has some aggregates, like User, Car, ...

**Question:**
Because these aggregates has mutable state, should i convert these aggregates to actors?, they have mutable state and seems that actors are a solution that fits to this.

Answer (score 0):

Mutable state is not the reason you should want to use Actors. Especially if you want to expose that mutable state to the outer world. The main argument for use of Akka and Actors is scalability and concurrency. In other cases it just adds unnecessary level of complexity.

Additionally, actors follow Erlang's "let it crash" fault-tolerance model. It means that there is always a chance that your actor breaks and you lose your state. Typically actors with the important state are moved to the top of the actor hierarchy (with the idea that it's better to propagate all risky operations to your child actors, so in case of the failure they crash and you reboot them, keeping all the important data in place).

Regarding mutable actor state I recommend you to read [that](http://spiridonov.pro/2015/10/08/akka-internal-state/) article and [these](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/5-actors.md) best state handling practices.

Update: it depends on the way how aggregations work. If it's something cheap and you can live with losing the data (because you can easily rebuild it upon actor restart) then go for it.